# inconsistent datatypes expected DATE got BINARY Hiberante Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

```
 <named-query name="Category.getids1">
    <query>
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT spov.versionId
        FROM SpecificationCategoryVersion spov
        WHERE ?1 is null OR spov.releaseDate is null]]>         
    </query>
</named-query>

<named-query name="Category.getids2">
    <query>
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT spov.versionId
        FROM SpecificationCategoryVersion spov
        WHERE ?1 is null OR spov.releaseDate <=  ?1         
        ]]>         
    </query>
</named-query>

<named-query name="Category.getids3">
    <query>
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT spov.versionId
        FROM SpecificationCategoryVersion spov
        WHERE ?1 is null OR spov.releaseDate is null OR spov.releaseDate <=  ?1         
        ]]>         
    </query>
</named-query>

   @Repository("specificationCategoryRepository")
   public interface SpecificationCategoryRepository extends
   JpaRepository<SpecificationCategory, Long>{
   ...

  @Query(name = "Category.getids1")
List<String> getIds1(Date validOn);

@Query(name = "Category.getids2")
List<String> getIds2(Date validOn);

@Query(name = "Category.getids3")
List<String> getIds3(Date validOn);

}
```

When the three methods invoked with null, getIds1 works as expected,

but getIds2, getIds3 raise the following complain:

```
SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY
```

Amazingly, the respective native SQLs:

```
select specificat0_.VERSION_ID as col_0_0_  
from SPEC_CATEGORY_VERSION specificat0_ 
where ? is null or specificat0_.RELEASE_DATE<=?
```

and

```
select specificat0_.VERSION_ID as col_0_0_ 
from SPEC_CATEGORY_VERSION specificat0_ 
where ? is null 
    or specificat0_.RELEASE_DATE is null 
    or specificat0_.RELEASE_DATE<=?
```

works properly when '?' is replaced with null.

Btw, **SPEC_CATEGORY_VERSION.RELEASE_DATE** is **nullable**

**Environment**

**DB:** Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

**Java:** 
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

**Server:**  Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.3.3.GA

**Dialect**      :HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

**Version**      :HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1

Any help in this regard will be more than welcome.

Comment: Well of course they do... You are using `?1` how can a parameter be a column name and a valid date?

Comment: @M.Deinum,  By '? is null' I'm checking whether the input parameter is null or not? The native SQL will be select specificat0_.VERSION_ID as col_0_0_  
from SPEC_CATEGORY_VERSION specificat0_ 
where null is null or specificat0_.RELEASE_DATE<=null

Comment: I would expect that to fail for anything else then `null` not sure if you can check a value for null in a query (only a column value not a passed in value).